# Help identifying glass pattern

Tags: glass

We are trying to find a replacement for one of the sidelights on our door. The house was built in 1933 and 7 of the 8 side lights appear to be original. I haven’t been able to find this patter anywhere.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're likely to find someone here who can help ID it, but you may as well take your pics (and glass dimensions) to a couple of local glass/restoration/architectural salvage places to see if they can help. You'll probably need to go there anyway to buy a replacement piece. If you can find it online, buy local anyway (if you can).

Comment: I used to do Victorian remodels and found a custom glass shop for some of the Art Deco patterns. In reality they never quite match and in many cases the glass needs to be replaced. I learned 100 year old glass is thinner at the top than the bottom and it breaks easily so in some cases it is best to get an available pattern from the era and replace all of them. If you have a custom pattern cast I would get enough to replace all of them with a spare or 4 and make sure to order enough for any others with the same pattern as the setup is the big $ after that it gets cheap by comparison.

Comment: These are likely old and not made commercially any longer.  If so you may have some luck with a local "artisan" glass maker.  Not cheap but possibly your only option if you need an exact match.

Comment: Echoing @FreeMan - Refab St Louis is an architectural salvage place https://www.refabstl.org/  that has a huge assembly of collected pieces including many doors.  The builder of your house probably built other houses in your area.  Doors from those houses might have been kept because they are nice.   Or maybe you will walk your dog and see that they are tearing down a house with a door like yours 3 blocks from you, and you can claim the door.

Answer (score 4):

This is a 'Glue Chipped' glass rather than a pattern.  Each pane of glue chipped glass is effectively unique due to the process.  First the glass surface is sandblasted.  Then glue is applied, which adheres to the sandblasted surface.  When the glue is removed it pulls away some of the glass surface leaving a uniquely 'chipped' finish.  Double chipped glass undergoes the procedure twice but requires a thicker glass because chipping will obviously weaken the strength.

Glue Chipping was often used to create signage for shops and bars by using a pattern stencil during sandblasting.  Geometric designs were also created this way.
[image]

Some more examples and info on my blog here - (I / we dont sell old glass btw, its content only, and my own research)   https://sashwindowspecialist.com/blog/usa-old-textured-window-glass-id/

Simon

Comment: Even if you disclose affiliation to the linked resources, promoting your content repeatedly and/or needlessly could be considered to be spam. Please see [How to not be a spammer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: @cigien On the other hand, if it legitimately answers the question, it should be OK. But I think (which is one of the suggestions on the "How to not be a spammer" page) including some images here would help - e.g., samples that are similar enough to the pictures in the question to show that the information is relevant. This is also the kind of thing where if we had blogging capability (or a true Wiki or "articles" or something) then the full information could be stored here - but putting the whole blog as an Answer just wouldn't work - and would be hard to find.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a spammer and will only comment on an area I have extensive knowledge of.  If I post any link to my own blog content then it will never be to a page that sells you anything.  I have 35 years of specialist experience with Heritage Conservation and have conducted extensive research of Victorian archives, which I publish on my blog post/website.  I have answered the question asked fully, and have left a link to back up my answer.  Regards  Simon

Comment: Your intentions are clearly to not be spamming. Your answers are self-contained, useful, and the links to your blog are relevant and are supporting information to your answers. However, note the second sentence in the link I shared, which says "some, **(but not all)* ...". So far, you appear to have 2 answers and both link to your blog. I don't think it's an issue yet, it's just that it might become an issue if many more of your answers follow this patter, so I thought I'd mention it. I'm certainly not implying that you're a spammer, or that your intentions are bad.

Answer (score 2):

That is called a "glue" pattern. I believe it is called that because traditional method involved slopping hide glue on the glass and pressing it while still hot. There is really no way to match any particular glue pattern *exactly* because the pattern varies with each batch.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Each of the 7 others are a different version of the same pattern. So that would make sense. Knowing what the method is called will help a lot on my search.